# Unable to locate an element in an html dom which is inside and object tag in selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am working on automating test on an html page using selenium in c# where the parent/outer html page has an object tag and in turn inside this object tag we have another html page. Here is how the sample html looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head><body id="divAjaxParent">
<div id="_ctl0_BodyContent_divObject" class="object-loading" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 60%; position: relative; width: 100%;">
<object id="abcd1234" style="height: 100%; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%;" data="abcd.ashx?action=dosimething&amp;sessionguid=1234567890">
#document == $0
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tool title</title>
  <base href="/deploy/">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body class="no-scrolling">
  <app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="7.1.4">
  <div _ngcontent-c0=""><div _ngcontent-c0="" class="route-placeholder clearfix">
    <app-dnl-dummyapp _nghost-c1="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <clr-modal _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c3="" class="ng-tns-c3-0 open">
    <button _ngcontent-c3="" class="close ng-tns-c3-0 ng-star-inserted" type="button" aria-label="Close" style="">
    <clr-icon _ngcontent-c3="" class="ng-tns-c3-0" shape="close" role="none">
    <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" focusable="false" role="img">
    <path class="clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-1" d="sdfggtrrr"></path></svg></clr-icon></button>
    <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="modal-title-wrapper" tabindex="0" id="clr-id-0"><div _ngcontent-c1="" class="modal-title font-28-regular">What do you want to do?</div></div></div>
    <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="modal-body" tabindex="0"><p _ngcontent-c1="">Description about the button options</p></div><div _ngcontent-c1="" class="modal-footer">
    <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn btn-outline" type="button">DO SOMETHING</button>
    <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn btn-primary verfy-btn" type="button">SO SOMTHING ELSE</button></div></div></div>
    <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="clr-sr-only">End of Modal Content</div></div>
    <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="modal-backdrop ng-trigger ng-trigger-fade" aria-hidden="true"></div></div></clr-modal>
    </app-dnl-dummyapp></div><a _ngcontent-c0="" class="invisible" href=""></a><div _ngcontent-c0="" appsizewatcher="" id="dummy_12345"></div></div></app-root>
</body></html>
</object>
</div></section></body></html>
```

I need to locate the button "do something" and "do something else" button and click on it.
I have tried using switching frame method but it didn't work.
I have also tried changing window handle, that too didn't work.

Through the findelement function, I can go up to object tag but not beyond that. Also tried searching for solution in stackoverflow but couldn't find the relevant bit. Could someone please help.

==================================================================

I have got some lead on it so editing the question and adding further bits here. The solution is something like this. I locate the object tag by id. The 'data' attribute of object tag contains the url of inner html, so I fetch it. Then I need driver to navigate to this inner url. From there on I am able to locate the element inside the inner html.

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("abcd1234"));
string innerurl = element.GetAttribute("data");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(innerurl);
```

However this leads to another problem, previously outer html was opened in browser and only a part of it containing the inner html, but with the above solution, inner html is loaded again directly in browser and not within its parent html. and webelemets of parent are lost. So the new question is, how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the below. This is angular code so you may need to add a wrapper for Protractor. We have always been able to find elements without using  Protractor though.

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-outline']")).Click();
FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary verfy-btn']")).Click();
```

or

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='DO SOMETHING']")).Click();
FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='SO SOMTHING ELSE']")).Click();
```

Switch to Another Window:

```
    public static string SwitchToPopup()
    {
        var mainHandle = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        var handles = Driver.WindowHandles;

        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            if (mainHandle == handle)
            {
                continue;
            }
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            break;
        }
        var result = Url;
        return result;

    }

    public static void GoToMainHandle()
    {
        var handles = Driver.WindowHandles;
        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already tried it but it doesn't work. As I mentioned in my question, locating element works only up till object tag, not for anything beyond. It doesn't even locate html lag which is right after object tag.

Comment: Have a link to the page?

Comment: No sorry, that's an internal application so can't really share that.

Comment: I updated my answer. Try using that to switch to in and see if it works. Without the entire html, I can't see if you have an iframe. It seems like you have a popup so try the SwitchToPopup and then GoToMainHandle when you are done interacting with it.

Comment: Hello, thanks again. I tried your code but that also doesn't work. Infact I check the windowhandle count and it comes out as only 1. I also tried switching iframe and a combination of iframe and windowhandle, that too doesn't work :(

Comment: There there seems to be two iframe. I have tried switching to both and searched for element. But no luck.

Comment: I got some lead on this. See I have added additional details on my question. However now facing another issue. Would you like to take a look and see if something could be done about it.